# Confusing use of ようになる

Tags: grammar

A [news article](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010830131000/k10010830131000.html) is describing the phenomenon of lucky-dip bags in Tokyo libraries:

> どんな本が入っているかは**わからないようになっています**。いつもは読まない種類の本や読んだことがない作家を知ってもらおうと**考えて**、去年から始めました。
>   **It's reached the point where** you don't know what kind of books will be in them. It's expected that you will come to know authors you've never read and book types that you don't normally read, and it started last year.

The usual translation of "reached the point that" for ようになる does not seem to work here. Why would we ever have known what was in a lucky-dip bag? So, what is the function of ようになる in this sentence.

Also, is "expect" a valid translation of 考える in this context? I struggled with that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「～～ようになっている」＝ "to be (purposely) designed so that ~~", "to be designed in such a way that ~~", etc.

The TL "reached the point that" does not apply here.

Thus,

> 「どんな本が入っているかはわからないようになっています。」 means:
>
> "It is (intentionally) designed in such a way that you will not know what books are in (the bag)."

Finally,

> Also, is "expect" a valid translation of 考える in this context?

Yes, it is.  Here, it means "***to anticipate***", "***to hope***", etc.